# Identity of Star-of-David kosher symbol

Tags: kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification, symbols-symbology

What is the certifying agency that uses a kosher symbol comprised of a Star-of-David containing another odd-looking symbol within it?:

[image: kosher symbol]

It is carried by, e.g., Byrne Dairy milks (of New York State).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [the Vaad Hakashruth of the Capital District](http://www.vhcd.org/), [which the cRc currently says is acceptable](http://www.crcweb.org/agency_list.php).

Inside the star is a "V"-and-"h" combination with a "C" in the upper-left and a "D" in the lower-right: VHCD is the initialism of the organization's name.